# CSS region not working in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have the following in my css file but css region doesn't work.
There's no collapse or expand icon to click on.

But the C# region is working, just css region isn't.

```
/*#region shared styles */
.blah { background-color: red; }
.foo { line-height: 1.2em; }
/*endregion */
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your missing the '#' between the '*' and 'endregion'

try

```
/*#region shared styles */

.blah { background-color: red; }

.foo { line-height: 1.2em; }

/*#endregion */
```

Answer (score 14):

Not sure why, but after doing this, it works now:

- type `region` in css file and then press `tab` twice
- it automatically insert the css region signature

after that, it works on newly created css regions. but my old css region still doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio does not support CSS regions.

You need to install the [Web Essentials 2012 extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6), which adds CSS regions, along with a slew of other nice features.

Comment: According to this, it does support in Preview. I have RTM http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2011/09/16/new-css-editor-features-in-visual-studio-11-developer-preview.aspx Also, I have Web Essentials 2012 installed. But still doesn't work.