# Organize Stylesheets in Visual Studio 2013 with Region (Collapse and Expand )

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013

Is there any extension for VS2013 to make it possible to organize CSS files and collapse and expand some sections of .css files?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056096/css-region-not-working-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: Thanks, I could not find it before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ctrl+M, Ctrl+L (press in order) will toggle the sections

Comment: Frustrating this isn't the same as the Code window/editor shortcut: `CTRL M + O` (Collapse to Definitions)

Comment: After years working with nested scss, I finally found this! Changed my life.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the shortcuts under Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard. Here is a description: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Anchor_1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (visual studio 2010):

1. Select lines you want to collapse
2. Press Ctrl+M and Ctrl+H (in order)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/td6a5x4s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx